# How to give an `EditText` a label to its left side?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to give an `EditText` a label to its left side?

[image]

Comment: combine textview and editext

Comment: Yeah Vivek Please see the above image and letme know how i have to the requirement like that

Comment: Neeraj,i have only editext with me but my requirement in the editetxtbox i have to get an text with box in my edittext

Answer (score 0):

You can combine textview/imageview with edittext for that, for example like this one :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext_border_red"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView <!-- this one should be your text or image-->
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_logo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="@string/dialog_mobile"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/main_color"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

File->new->image asset-> here choose 1st drop down and select **Action bars and Tabs Icons**->then choose radio button *Asset type* **Text**->now next columns is *Text* here in "Aa" field Enter "F" and choose back ground.
now save it with some **img.png**

now In your EditText 
write add `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img.png"` like bellow

```
           <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Child's First Name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img.png" />
```

Comment: brahmy adigopula,if we give drawable left the icon is displayed left it is fine. but after icon i have to get a vertical line can u please let me know how to do that one.

Comment: if you set back ground color of image with "drak gray" the effect will be shown on edit text box.In the figure you attached way the edit text will looks like if you  set bg color for that image while creating it.